# Python sqlite3 Operational Error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying do delete a user from my database using python and sqlite.

```
import sqlite3

database_connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

delete_username_input = input("Which user you would like to delete?\n\n")
sql = ("DELETE * from USERS where USERNAME = ?")
args = (delete_username_input)
database_connection.execute(sql, args)
database_connection.commit()
database_connection.close()
```

When running the code above, I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "*": syntax error
```

Any idea what might be causing this error?

The table that I use has been created using the following syntax:

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE USERS
     (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
     USERNAME       TEXT    NOT NULL,
     PASSWORD       TEXT     NOT NULL,
     WINS           FLOAT   NOT NULL,
     LOSES         FLOAT    NOT NULL,
     GAMESPLAYED   FLOAT NOT NULL,
     WINPERCENT    FLOAT NOT NULL   );''')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is wrong. It should be

```
DELETE from USERS where USERNAME = ?
```

without the `*`

Check it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp)

Comment: Yes that's it, thank you. Also the database_connection.execute(sql, args) should've been database_connection.execute(sql, (args,)).